# Can't build project of Cocos2d-x on windows 8

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I followed the instruction from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9ObAzm6rnQ). No errors occured during the setup  but when importing to Eclipse, my project got a little red cross => can't build project. I tried to go through every folder in my project but I can't find any other errors. See this [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3QH139_mjileTlXVXZTWGUzclU/view?usp=sharing). I did move everything to C drive but... nothing better. Any helps would be highly appreciated :)

FYI:

Cocos v3.2,
Python 2.7.8,
Apache ANT 1.9.4.
NDK: r9 win 64﻿

Comment: If you click on the `Problems` tab it might actually give you a hint as to why it couldn't build.

Comment: Yeah right. That was stupid of me... I only thought errors come from my source code. Thank you :)